# SQL job fails when user is not logged into the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have currently one issue with a SQL job that always fails when the user is not logged in into the server.

The job is configured to run with a specific service account that has rights on the server our sql-server is in.

When i remote connect to the server and run the job I get no error and the job doesn't fail but when I'm not remote connected with the service account the job always fails.

The job type is "SQL Server Integration Services Package"

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to fix this?
Sorry for the vague question. Hope this is enough information.

[image: Picture of step]

[image]

Comment: You say it always fails...do you have an error message?

Comment: Added picture of the log job history

Comment: Instead of a picture can you post the actual error message?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting when it fails

Comment: Does it succeed when you right click run it, or is it succeeding if you are simply logged into the console and the schedule runs?  You may have to set the SQL Server Service agent to start with the same account that has rights.

Comment: When I right click run the job succeeds depending if I'm remote connected to the server with the service account or not. Same goes if it is 7:30 and the job runs on scheduled time.

Comment: what version of windows are you on?

Comment: The server is on Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: something to simply try would be to delete the job and remake it.  I hate saying that but sometimes it works :)

Comment: Ok will try doing that thank you for the help

Comment: Oh! Know what it might be?  I wonder if you need to be logged in to have the drives mapped properly to get to that package?  Maybe put the package local?  I can't tell if it's on a UNC or mapped drive from the picture.

Comment: After remaking the job the issue seems to have been fixed. I seem to be able to run without fail when not logged into the account at the moment! Thank you for the help @sniperd.

Comment: ha! great.  I'll write a short little answer.

Comment: @PedroLopes answer added, please accept and vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it can be as simple as deleting and remaking the scheduled task/job.  It could be related to:

- A stored/network password has changed since making the job
- A corrupted password
- Something just fat fingered, and round 2 gets it right
- A windows update has changed how security works